# Using definition of open set determine if A is open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> Let $x_{0} = (2,0,1,1)$ and determine whether $A = \{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R^4} : x^2+y^2=4, z >0, t \geq 0 \}$ is open or not.

$A$ is said to be open iff $\forall x \in A, \; \exists \varepsilon >0$ such that $\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset A$. It is easy to see $x_{0}\in A$ since $2^2+0^2=0,\; 1>0 ,\; 1\geq 0$ all properties of $A$ are satisfied. But I couldn't use the definition. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need $x_0$?

Comment: Given in the question

Comment: Ok, so the question is: why do you think it is helpful to prove that $A$ is open?

Comment: I don't think that though, I just verified that $x_{0} \in A$

Comment: I just don't know the way I have to use when I using the definition.

Comment: So, was the question also: "verify that $x_0 \in A$?

Comment: No, I just added it to the proof, however we cannot say it is a proof :D

Comment: HINT: Try to understand if you can build a ball of some radius around your given $x_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no, but I will answer an analogous question in 3 dimensions to help, rather than outright giving the answer to the original question. Then you can apply my answer in 3 dimensions to your 4-dimensional question.

Let $\ S = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} : x^2+z^2=1, y\geq0\}\subset \mathbb{R^3},\ $ and let $\ \varepsilon>0.$

Then $\ (1,0,0)\in S,\ $ and $\ \left(1,-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},0\right)\in\ B\left(\ (1,0,0),\ \varepsilon \right)\ $ in $\ \mathbb{R^3},\ $ because

$$\ \sqrt{(1- 1)^2 + \left(0-\left(-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\right)^2 + (0-0)^2 }\ = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon.$$ But $\ \left(1,-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},0\right)\notin S.\ $ In other words, there is no $\ \varepsilon>0\ $ such that $\ B\left(\ (1,0,0),\ \varepsilon \right)\subset S,\ $ proving that $\ S\ $ is not open.

Your $\ x_0\ $ is irrelevant, but you should do the same thing I did but for when $\ t = 0,\ $ for example, the point $\ (2,0,1,0).$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a ball $B_\epsilon(x_0)$ around your $x_0$ such that $ B_\epsilon(x_0) \subset A$. Can you do it?

Comment: I think the ball is $\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}((x,y,z,t)) = \{\sqrt[4]{(x-2)^4+y^4+(z-1)^4+(t-1)^4}\}$

Answer (score 0):

A is said to be open iff $\forall x \in \mathbb{A}, \; \exists \varepsilon > 0 \;$ such that $\mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}\subset \mathbb{A}$. For $x_{0}$ it is easy to see $x_{0} \in \mathbb{A}$. Let's build a ball around $x_{0}$:

$$\mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R^4}: \|(x,y,z,t)-(2,0,1,0)\| <\varepsilon\}$$

$$\mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R^4}:\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2+t^2}\}$$

Let $y=(2,-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},1,0) \in \mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}:$

$$\sqrt{(2-2)^2+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}+(1-1)^2+0^2}$$

$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$$

But $y \in \mathbb{A}$ since $-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ not $z > 0$. So $\mathbb{A}$ is closed.